# Vertical alignment of DIV's using relative positioning and inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem aligning DIV's vertically, when the contents within them have different height (although the DIV's themselves have a fixed size).

[See HTML example here (with inline CSS)](http://www.tomsoderlund.com/css_inline-block_relative.html)

I want the DIV's to "flow" like text, so I'd like to avoid using `position:absolute` if possible. I'm using `display: inline-block` to the DIV's won't collapse.

Comment: I found the answer in @Luke's answer to [Vertical alignment of empty inline-block elements][1]. A `vertical-align: top` in the collection_box style was all that was needed.

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885873/vertical-alignment-of-empty-inline-block-elements

Comment: Please add this comment as an answer and accept it, otherwise this question remains unnecessary unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `vertical-align` property - it doesn't matter which one, they all do the same thing, since they're the same size. If they're different sizes, use `vertical-align: middle`:

```
.collection_box {
    vertical-align: middle; /* or top, or bottom, if they're the same size */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Float them to the left:

```
.collection_box {
  float: left;
}
```