# Align span next to each other

Tags: css

I'm having some troubles getting span with text aligned with other span with no content. Take a look here:
http://jsfiddle.net/hp8Ak/

(As you can see the first span jumps down).

Here's my css:

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #377ca2;
    color: #fff;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertical alignment of empty inline-block elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885873/vertical-alignment-of-empty-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top;`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hp8Ak/1/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will accept your answer in 12 minutes (was not allowed to do it yet). Thanks man!