# Why setting display:none to an element inside inline-block div make inline-block not render as an inline-block;

Tags: css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .container{
            height: 400px;
            min-width: 200px;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid grey;
        }
        .item{
            border: 1px solid grey;
            margin: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"><div class="item" style="display: none;">123</div></div>
    <div class="container"><div class="item">123</div></div>
    <div class="container"><div class="item">123</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

the problem is when i add style="display: none;" to the first item, the containers not display inline. when i remove display:none , it's ok . 
anyone could tell me why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `display:none` to `visibility:hidden`, and it works.

This may class as a solution: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885873/vertical-alignment-of-empty-inline-block-elements) - the default alignment is baseline, and without any content in the div, there is no baseline. If you add vertical-align:top, you overcome this. That's why my 'solution' above works - visibility:hidden leaves the element inline - whereas display:none takes it out of the flow.

Comment: I'd like to know why also, and it's not beyond the established principles of scientific method for everyone to contribute solutions that allow us/someone to understand what's broken by seeing what doesn't break it.

Comment: This may class as a solution: [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885873/vertical-alignment-of-empty-inline-block-elements) - the default alignment is baseline, and without any content in the div, there is no baseline.  If you add `vertical-align:top`, you overcome this.  That's why my 'solution' above works - `visibility:hidden` leaves the element inline - whereas `display:none` takes it out of the flow.

Comment: Might wanna edit that into your answer proper ;)

Comment: Did that.  Go in peace.

Comment: Nice. FWIW, I try not to be as grumpy about this anymore as [I used to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246665/why-do-people-ask-why-questions-with-the-why-capitalized-and-over-formatted#comment807480_246666) (I'm not the original commenter). I still recommend in the future putting information most pertinent to the question in the actual answer and not in a comment after-the-fact.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I do not know the exact answer, but I can provide you a solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .container{
            height: 400px;
            min-width: 100px;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid grey;
        }
        .item{
            border: 1px solid grey;
            margin: 5px;
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"><div class="item" style="display: none;">123</div></div>
    <div class="container"><div class="item">123</div></div>
    <div class="container"><div class="item">123</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thks very much . do you know why this happened ?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
.item{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

to:

```
.item{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  float:left
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/djrr93wq/